# Discussing Whether Solutions to ODE Exist for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions

I am asked whether any solution for $y''+y'+y+y^3 =0$ exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here is what I am thinking:

First, introduce a change of variables $z_1 = y$, $z_2 = y'$ so that the equation given becomes the 1st order system:

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{z'_1\\z_2'}=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&-1}\pmatrix{z_1\\ z_2} +\pmatrix{0\\-z_1^3}
\end{equation}

After computing the Jacobian, we get that:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1-3z_1^2&-1}$

Now, we need to check whether $F(z_1,z_2)=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&-1}\pmatrix{z_1\\ z_2} +\pmatrix{0\\-z_1^3}$ is Lipschitz.

Clearly, $F$ is continuous (component wise). Note then if we compute the operator norm of the Jacobian, we get (using the sup norm):

$\left\lVert\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right\rVert_\infty = \max${$|1|$, $|1+3z_1^2|+|1|$}

Since $3x^2 +1 \neq 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then the above expression is just 
\begin{equation}
1 +|3z_1^2 +1| \leq 2 +3|z_1|^2
\end{equation}

Because of the $z_1$ term above, then the Jacobian is not bounded. Thus, $F$ cannot be (globally) Lipschitz.

If we did assume that $z_1 =  y$ was bounded beforehand, then it might work. However, we're not given any further assumptions.

I am aware that there are alternate methods to solving this problem, maybe finding a potential function $V(y)$ and checking if $V'(y) \leq 0$. However, I don't want to go that route, as we can only use material we've covered so far. We just got to linear systems last lecture.

Does this work? I feel there's something I am overlooking.

Comment: Too bad that it isn't allowed to use a potential function. This is probably the easiest way here. I'm not 100% sure, however, that all solutions exist for all times. However, it's quite easy to find a few that do exist for all times.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the equation by $y'$ and integrate between $0$ and $x$ to get
$$
\frac12\,(y'(x))^2+\int_0^x(y'(t))^2\,dt+\frac12\,y(x)^2+\frac14\,y(x)^4=C.
$$
It follows easily that $y$ and $y'$ are bounded on any interval $[0,a]$ with $a>0$, so that the solution is defined on $[0,\infty)$. If $x<0$ we have
$$
\frac12\,(y'(x))^2+\frac12\,y(x)^2+\frac14\,y(x)^4=C+\int_x^0(y'(t))^2\,dt,
$$
and things are not clear. However, we have
$$
\frac12\,(y'(x))^2\le C+\int_x^0(y'(t))^2\,dt,
$$
and we apply Gronwall's lemma to $(y'(x))^2$ and show that it is bounded on bounded intervals $[-a,0]$ with $a>0$. The same is true then of $y$, showing that the solution is defined on $(-\infty,0)$. Observe that in general the solution will be unbounded.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I am not sure if we can do it this way, since we are only allowed to use techniques we learned so far, which are very limited (we just started talking about matrix exponentials last lecture). Is there another more elementary way of doing this?

Comment: Multiplying y $y’$ and integrating is a standard procedure to study non-linear differential equations. I do not knowof